# Why is this API call with $.ajax and $.post not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script lang="javascript">$.ready(function () {
$.post("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR,GBP", function(data) {
  alert(data)

})
}) </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is meant to pull {"BTC":0.0684,"USD":294.38,"EUR":251.24,"GBP":227.87} from the cryptocompare API and then give an alert but it is showing nothing. I have also checked in devtools and there is nothing outgoing in

Comment: Shouldn't `$.ready` be `$( document ).ready` ? https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Where are you passing the POST data? I believe it should be `$.post("https://...", {"field":"value"}, function(data) { alert(data); });`. Maybe you want to use `$.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `$.get()` not `$.post()`
This should work.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script lang="javascript">$(document).ready(function () {
$.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR,GBP", function(data) {
  alert(data)

})
}) </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Either

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

OR

```
$(function(){


})
```

There is nothing to post, probably you need `$.get()`

```js
$(function() {
  $.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR,GBP", function(data) {
    alert(data)
    console.log(data)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ready` syntax is incorrect.  Also, in this exact case, you can just use `$.get` although it works either way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script lang="javascript">$(document).ready(function () {
$.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR,GBP", function(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data))

})
}) </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably `$.get()` instead of `$.post()`.

Although `$.post(url, data, handler)` is commonly used for POST (or `$.get(url, handler)` for GET), it would be preferrable to use `.done()` and `.fail()`:

```
$.post("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR,GBP", {
    "field1" : "value1",
    "field2" : "value2"
}).done(function(data) {
    alert('Success: ' + data);
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert('Error: ' + error);
});
```

For GET:

```
$.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR,GBP").done(function(data) {
    alert('Success: ' + data);
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert('Error: ' + error);
});
```

Also note that this should be done when the DOM is ready (if you need to add the data to some HTML element or stuff like that):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Here
    });
</script>
```